# Spectral theorem/ exchanging limit of series and operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am currently learning quantum mechanics and there is one typical scenario i encounter in my physics books:

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $A: \operatorname{Dom}(A)\to \mathcal{H}$ is a (linear) operator, $Dom(A)\subseteq\mathcal{H}$. In addition, let $\mathcal{B}:=\{v_n: n \in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a set of eigenvectors of $A$: $A(v_n)=\lambda_nv_n$.

If there is a $v \in \operatorname{Dom}(A)$ and a sequence of coefficients $(c_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ with $v=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c_nv_n$, then the authors write $A(v)=A(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c_nv_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c_nA(v_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(c_n\lambda_n)v_n$.

From what i know, A is **not** continuous in general, but this is a special case of the spectral theorem. I think that a physicist would write $A=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|v_n\rangle\langle v_n|$ and call this the **spectral theorem for the discrete case**.
The problem is that when looking into a math book about the spectral theorem, i see a lot of integrals and things get very complicated. So it would be nice if someone could explain this special case of the spectral theorem (its requirements and statements), or suggest a good source.

Comment: I don't think  anything weaker than continuity will be enough.

Comment: Potentially, in the case of a differential operator, it is genuinely continuous on some Sobolev-space and, accordingly, we might expect the above series to converge there, and not just in, say, $L^2$?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I think that this would be too specific, since physicits often do that "trick" with the Hamiltonian operator.

Comment: You can do something like this for general operators. Equip Dom(A) with the norm $\sqrt{||x||^2+||A(x)||^2}$ (i.e. force $A$ to be continuous) and look at its completion with respect to this norm. Naturally, this is equivalent to saying that we expect the above sum to converge to the right thing before we start performing our calculation, so it's not useful for actually verifying anything unless you have a good idea of what the resulting Hilbert space looks like for other reasons.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Physicits use this equation all the time, although a selfadjoint operator doesn't have to be continuous. This makes me wonder if there is some theorem that allows physicits to do so. By the way, i edited my post to make clearer why this might be related to the spectral theorem.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Isn't this cheating? :D

Comment: Well... as said, it's not likely to be very useful unless this becomes a Hilbert space that you have some familiarity with - for instance a Sobolev Space (this is why a general differential operator is a good example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator $A$ is typically not continuous, but since it is self-adjoint, it is **closed** (see below). One of the conclusions of the spectral theorem is that $v\in \mathrm{Dom}(A)$ is equivalent to the convergence of the series of nonnegative numbers
$$
\sum_n \lambda_n^2\lvert c_n\rvert^2. $$ 
This implies that the sequence $
S_N:= \sum_{n=1}^N \lambda_n c_n v_n
$
is convergent, because $$\lVert S_M-S_N\rVert=\left\lVert \sum_{n=N}^M \lambda_n c_n v_n\right\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{n=N}^M \lvert c_n\rvert^2\lambda_n^2} ,$$ 
so $S_N$ satisfies the Cauchy condition.

The formula 
$$\tag{1}
A\sum_n c_n v_n= \sum_n \lambda_n c_n v_n$$ 
is now proven by using the fact that $A$ is **closed**$^{[1]}$. Indeed, $A(\sum_1^N c_n v_n)=\sum_{1}^N \lambda_n c_n v_n$, and we just saw that the right-hand side converges. Since $\sum_n \lvert c_n\rvert^2<\infty$, by reasoning as above we see that $\sum_1^N c_n v_n$ converges, so by the closedness property we can pass to the limit and prove (1).

**Remark**. Here we supposed that $A$ has a discrete spectrum. This means that every spectral value is an eigenvalue and that there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$ made of eigenvectors. If this is not the case, the series $\sum_n$ have to be replaced by integrals. This is why mathematics books explain the spectral theorem in terms of spectral integrals. The basic idea, however, is already fully contained in the discrete spectrum case.

---

$[1]$. This means that if $f_n\in \mathrm{Dom}(A)$ is such that $f_n\to f$ and $Af_n \to g$, then $f\in \mathrm{Dom}(A)$ and $g=Af$.

Comment: First of all, thank you. However, i have two questions:  **1.** How is the limit with N **and** M going to infinity defined? **2.** Is A having a discrete spectrum the only requirement or are there any extra requirements (for example the set of eigenvectors being a Hilbert basis)?

Comment: 1. It is just a shortcut for the Cauchy condition. This post proves that $S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N c_n \lambda_n v_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal H$. 2. Here, we only used that $\{v_n\ :\ n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an orthonormal set; it actually is a Hilbert basis. For a general operator, such a Hilbert basis might have to be replaced with a set of *generalized eigenfunctions*; for example, the generalized eigenfunctions of the momentum operator on the line are complex exponentials $e^{ikx}$. This is technically more difficult, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you again. Unfortunately, i don't see how $A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n v_n=\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}A\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_n v_n$ follows from $S_N:= \sum_{n=1}^N \lambda_n c_n v_n$ being convergent.

Comment: The formula is true for finite sums. Pass to the limit by using the same argument as before.

Comment: I see that both sides of the equation exist, but i don't see why they are equal...what argument do you mean?

Comment: The fact that both sides are equal for finite sums doesn't mean that the two sides are equal for $N=\infty$ - but that's not what you mean anyway, do you?

Comment: The missing ingredient is that A is **closed**. That's the property you should use to conclude that the formula holds.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, i didn't notice that you edited your answer. In your answer to my first comment, you wrote that we only used that $\{v_n: N\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal set and added: "it actually is a Hilbert basis". To be honest, i'm not sure that i understood what you meant: Did you mean that we can assume that $\{v_n\ :\ n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a Hilbert basis (because a Hilbert basis made of eigenvectors exists), although we dont need to in order to prove equation (1)?

Comment: One last thing: When you said that A having a discrete spectrum "means that every spectral value is an eigenvalue and that there exists an orthonormal basis of H made of eigenvectors", did you mean that this is a consequence of A having a discrete spectrum or is "A has a discrete spectrum" defined like that?

Comment: Well, pause for a moment. :) This is not a textbook, I just want to give **some** ideas. Anyway; yes, equation (1) only needs orthonormality. "Having discrete spectrum" is a way of saying I just invented. What I meant is what you said, which is also what I wrote. Maybe "a purely discrete spectrum" would have been a better terminology, but again, here we are just having an informal discussion.